# Content of file to tree format using python

Tags: python, treeview

I have a file containing a file "dir.txt" with the below data:

```
/home/abc/a.txt
/home/abc/b.txt
/home/xyz/test
/home/xyz/test/d.txt
/home/xyz/test/e.txt
/home/xyz/test/f.txt
/home/xyz
/home/xyz/g.txt
```

I want to parse the file and get the output like

```
/home/abc/a.txt
          b.txt
/home/xyz/test/d.txt
               e.txt
               f.txt
/home/xyz/g.txt
```

Using python, basically need to print the content in a tree format. How would I process it?

Comment: your edit completely changes the original question! If you need to expand the already-posted solutions you need to narrow down your problem and post another question!

Comment: wtf? Panther24, we send you codez of a silver plate and you're coming in and makes all of look like idiots who don't know/understand basics of Python!

Comment: @SilentGhost, sorry, but am just a new kid on the block learning new stuff. Don't bother do look at what I've posted, I should be able to handle it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `os.path.split` on every path, find the first dirname and print path as it is. find it length and print so many spaces before next basename, on change of the dirname repeat as before.

```
>>> import os.path    
>>> olddir = None
>>> for name in open('input.txt'):
    dirname, fname = os.path.split(name)
    if olddir != dirname:
        prefix = ' ' * (len(dirname) +1)
        olddir = dirname
        print(name)
    else:
        print(prefix + fname)


/home/abc/a.txt
          b.txt
/home/xyz/test/d.txt
               e.txt
               f.txt
/home/xyz/g.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import os.path

txt = """/home/abc/a.txt
/home/abc/b.txt
/home/xyz/test/d.txt
/home/xyz/test/e.txt
/home/xyz/test/f.txt
/home/xyz/g.txt"""

last_d = ''
for l in txt.split('\n'):
    (d, n) = os.path.split(l)
    if d == last_d:
        d = ' ' * len(last_d)
    else:
        last_d = d
    print('%s/%s' % (d, n))
```

Comment: @ghostdog74: there was no indication in the answer that it might be the case, even if it is so, adding `sorted` to `for` clause is trivial.

Comment: I've changed the source a little bit!!

Answer (score 2):

@Op,use a dictionary. Use the paths as the key and the file names as values

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for line in open("file"):
    line=line.strip()
    s='/'.join(line.split("/")[:-1])
    d[s].append(line.split("/")[-1])

for i,j in d.iteritems():
    print i,j
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
/home/xyz ['g.txt']
/home/xyz/test ['d.txt', 'e.txt', 'f.txt']
/home/abc ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
```

Do the formatting as described by the answers others had posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> filenames="""/home/abc/a.txt
... /home/abc/b.txt
... /home/xyz/test/d.txt
... /home/xyz/test/e.txt
... /home/xyz/test/f.txt
... /home/xyz/g.txt""".split()
>>> 
>>> import os
>>> prev=''
>>> for n in filenames:
...     path,name = os.path.split(n)    
...     if path==prev:
...         print " "*len(prev)+" "+name
...     else:
...         print n
...         prev=path
... 
/home/abc/a.txt
          b.txt
/home/xyz/test/d.txt
               e.txt
               f.txt
/home/xyz/g.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate take that offers a different output, just in case the OP would prefer this format:

```
/home/abc/a.txt
          b.txt
      xyz/test/d.txt
               e.txt
               f.txt
          g.txt
```

then this code:

```
import os

def pretty_printer(seq_of_strings):
    previous_line= ''
    for line in seq_of_strings:
        last_sep= os.path.commonprefix([previous_line, line]).rfind(os.path.sep)+1
        yield ' '*last_sep + line[last_sep:]
        previous_line= line
```

might do the trick.

Should the OP comment that they don't need it at all, I'll delete this answer.